# how to bind .json file to auto complete drop down list in MVC AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-directive

I'm having large data of city names in .json file, i want to bind that all city names to my auto complete drop down list by using Mvc AngularJS so is there any way to do that,thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt
```

You can make use of this plugin I think. Here's how you can use it.

```
<angucomplete-alt id="members"
    placeholder="Search members"
    pause="400"
    selected-object="selectedCity"
    remote-url="http://myserver.com/api/user/find?s="
    remote-url-data-field="results"
    title-field="name"
    input-class="form-control form-control-small"/>
```

On server side you will receive the typed string as GET parameter.

```
Request.QueryString["type"];
```

Your server function should return the result in following JSON format.

```
{
    results : [{'name': 'first city', 'name': 'second city'}]
}
```

**2nd Option**

In case you have to stick with static json file then you can use following approach as well. This will also work fast as all cities and loaded once and then filtering happens locally.

In Template

```
<div angucomplete-alt id="ex1"
  placeholder="Search cities"
  maxlength="50"
  pause="100"
  selected-object="selectedCity"
  local-data="cities"
  search-fields="name"
  title-field="name"
  minlength="1"
  input-class="form-control form-control-small"
  match-class="highlight">
  </div>
```

then in your controller add this. This loads your json file into cities array which is used by the directive for auto complte purpose

```
$scope.cities = [];

$http.get('http://server/cities.json')..success(function(response) {
    $scope.cities = response.data;
});
```

Comment: thank you for responding me but my json is in my solution of my project so how i can achieve that?

Comment: well that's pretty simple then.. Just move that to a service and define a variable and store your json in that. Then in your controller you can replace this line ( 2nd example) to this $scope.cities = YOURSERVICE.cities

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-options="color.Name for color in Colors"

<script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
        app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $window) {
            $scope.Colors = [{
                Id: 1,
                Name: 'Red'
            }, {
                Id: 2,
                Name: 'Blue'
            }, {
                Id: 3,
                Name: 'Green'
            }];
        });
    </script>

     <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
        <select ng-model="ddlColors" ng-options="color.Name for color in Colors track by color.Id">
        </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller code

```
   var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
    app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $window) {
        $scope.Fruits = [{
            Id: 1,
            Name: 'Apple'
        }, {
            Id: 2,
            Name: 'Mango'
        }, {
            Id: 3,
            Name: 'Orange'
        }];
    });
```

HTML Code

```
     <label class="item item-input item-select">
        <div class="input-label" style="color:#387ef5;">
        Type of call :
        </div>
        <select name="fruitType"  class="form-control" ng-change="getSectedTypeValue(selectedID)" ng-model="selectedID" ng-options="    fruitType as fruitType.Name for fruitType in Fruits track by fruitType.Id"  value="{{fruitType.Id}}" required>
        <option value=""> Select Call Type </option>
        </select>
    </label>
```

Comment: its works fine when i used simple drop down , but the problem is that i want to use auto complete drop down when ever i used the script for auto complete drop down the data is not get bind

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    var config = {
        '.chosen-select': {},
        '.chosen-select-deselect': { allow_single_deselect: true },
        '.chosen-select-no-single': { disable_search_threshold: 10 },
        '.chosen-select-no-results': { no_results_text: 'Oops, nothing found!' },
        '.chosen-select-width': { width: "95%" }
    }
    for (var selector in config) {
        $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
    }
  </script>

Comment: i'm using this script for auto complete drop down